# How to add a Keras Layer to crop images?

Tags: opencv, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

I need to add a layer to my `Sequential` model (actually will the first layer) in order to crop images to remove parts except than faces. For face recognition, I use `OpenCV`. Therefore, just like the `Transformations` in `PyTorch`, I need a layer that applies this transformation to the images and passes the output to the next layers.

p.s. Using the latest stable releases of both of `Tensorflow` and `Keras` which are `1.14.0`, and `2.3.0`, respectively.

Comment: Does it need to be in the middle of the model? For inputs the best to do is to use a generator or a `keras.utils.Sequence`, both with `model.fit_generator()`.

Comment: I already use both of them, the problem is I need a layer that I will do some custom operations such as cropping images, etc. So, how can I add such a layer to my model?

Comment: It it does need to be in the middle of the model?

Comment: Yes, there is a possible way which PyTorch provides. I think you suggest doing all these stuff completely isolated from the model?